# Xposed: How to hook method that using PendingIntent

Tags: android, location, android-pendingintent, xposed

I want to fake location in android. In android, there is a way for getting location using `PendingIntent`. Here is an example:

```
        LocationManager service = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        String proximitys = "ACTION";
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(proximitys);
        LocationReceiver mReceiver = new LocationReceiver();
        registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
        Intent intent = new Intent(proximitys);
        PendingIntent proximityIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
                intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

        service.requestLocationUpdates("network", 1000, 0.001f, proximityIntent);
```

And `BroadcastReceiver` will receive event when new location change:

```
public class LocationReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        //Do this when the system sends the intent
        Bundle b = intent.getExtras();
        Location loc = (Location)b.get(android.location.LocationManager.KEY_LOCATION_CHANGED);
    }
}
```

So, I want to hook this method. But I don't know how to hook this kind of method (that using `PendingIntent`). because `PendingIntent` will have data in "some future", and I don't know when it will happen. So hooking both before and after of method `requestLocationUpdates` seem not work because at that time, `PendingIntent` doesn't have any data yet.

Please tell me how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to intercept the broadcast receiver, not the pending intent. You can intercept `LocationReceiver.onReceive` and change the contents of the intent.

To do so intercept the `onReceive` by defining a `beforeHookedMethod`. Use its parameter (`MethodHookParam params`) to retrieve the intent (`params.args[1]`) and change its extras (`intent.replaceExtras(bundle)`).

Make sure your new bundle has the same key (`android.location.LocationManager.KEY_LOCATION_CHANGED`) and as value you can set your own location:

```
Location loc = new Location("yourprovider");
loc.setLatitude(66.6);
loc.setLongitude(66.6);
```